# linq which uses string instead of char

Tags: c#, linq

```
string x = "";
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("",x.Where(y => y == "")));
```

y = char.
how do I do this y = string?

I want "y = string" and I can compare whether this string is equal to this emoji

Comment: Use IndexOf method

Comment: What exactly is the idea here? A string consists of chars. Using LINQ in this way is like iterating over all the chars while you're looking for more than a single char.

Comment: I don't think this way will work, since  isn't a char, it's two chars: \ud83d and \ude01 - you'll need to look for both of them next to each other.

Comment: Note that `U+1F601 GRINNING FACE WITH SMILING EYES` does *not* fit in a `char` as that only holds a single 16-bit code point; it's more appropriately a substring of your original string.

Comment: Splitting into an array of strings helped now y = string